# Adding new fields using schema.xml is supported way?

Tags: solr

I'm using "schema.xml" to manage schema in solr-5.5.3 and I want to add some fields to schema.
I know it's recommended that I should use manage-schema and SchemaAPI to add fields, but solr has been already running in customer environment so I don't want to do so.

I tried to add fields in following ways:

1.Editting schema.xml

```
 <field name="newfield" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

2.Reloading core or restart solr.

I can see "newfield" in SchemaBrowser. I executed query including condition like "newfield:*" and it worked fine. It looks solr is recognizing new fields I added.

I have 2 questions.

- **Is this officialy supported?**
- **I see adding fields doesn't have any effect on existing documents. If I want those to have new fields, do I have to re-index?(In short, deleting all existing documents and inserting again)**

Comment: when the data is already in the schema solr, then you add a new field, then all you have to do is update the data again.

as long as the "id" field entered is the same, the data will be overwritten

Comment: Thanks for replying.
You mean I don't have to delete, but just updating all indexes with new field I added?

Comment: yups .. as long as the value of the "id" field must be the same, then the data will be overwritten. otherwise, the data will be added as new data

Comment: Very helpful. I recognize adding new field via schema.xml is officially suppoted. Is it right?

Comment: with a note, still you have to enter all the fields when updating data

Comment: maybe that's true. so far i have done the same thing

Comment: What a relief. Thank you very much. I close this case.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this officialy supported?

Yes.

> I see adding fields doesn't have any effect on existing documents. If
> I want those to have new fields, do I have to re-index?(In short,
> deleting all existing documents and inserting again)

When the data is already in Solr's index and you add a new field, then you have to update the data again. As long as the value for the "id" field is the same, the old data will be overwritten.